# Stretch divider and iframe to screen height

Tags: html, css

On my page I have 3 dividers, for a header, content, and footer. I want to make my iframe inside my content divider stretch to the screen height, along with the divider that contains it (minus the height of the header and footer). How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can absolutely position your `header`/`content`/`footer` divs and relatively position the `iframe` within the content div:

HTML--

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS--

```
#header {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100px;
    background : red;
}
#content {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 100px;
    bottom     : 100px;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    background : green;
}
#content > iframe {
    position   : relative;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : purple;
}
#footer {
    position   : absolute;
    bottom     : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100px;
    background : blue;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/dghW4/